# Why volatile and synchronized statements cannot avoid thread interference here?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
package simple;

public class ThreadInterference {
    public static volatile Integer count = 1000;

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;
                count--;
                count++;
                count--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(count);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new MyThread());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();

        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

The `count` variable is marked as `volatile` but the output is:

```
1000
1230
```

If I change to `synchronized` statements, thread interference also happens:

```
package simple;

public class ThreadInterference {
    public static Integer count = 1000;

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                synchronized(count) {
                    count++;
                    count--;
                    count++;
                    count--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(count);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new MyThread());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();

        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

output of this time is:

```
1000
1008
```

Why?

Comment: The first one is easy -- `volatile` makes accesses visible and ordered, [not atomic](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html). Two threads each doing a "read, modify, write" can stomp on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, you have two separate problems.  The first one is that `count++` (and `count--`) isn't an atomic operation, even for primitive `int` types.  So this won't work without some sort of locking or other concurrency handling.  For `count++` where count is an `int`, the compiler generates something like the following byte code instructions:

```
    getstatic count
    iconst_1
    iadd
    putstatic count
```

This is not likely to be atomic even if/when compiled to native code.

The second problem is that you are not locking on a consistent object, so operations are not serialised.  The code:

```
   count++; // "count" is an "Integer" object type.
```

Creates a new object.  In essence it does something like the following:

```
   count = Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1);
```

So your `count` object is getting replaced by a new object, and subsequent entry into the `synchronized` section will be synchronizing against a different object.

As a safety tip, if you are using `synchronized (someObject)`, where `someObject` is a class or instance field, then it's a good idea to make that field `final`.  That way it can't be inadvertently reassigned to a different value.

There are two straightforward solutions to the problem that I can think of.  One with locking against a specific object used for locking like so:

```
public class ThreadInterference {
  public static final Object COUNT_LOCK = new Object();
  public static int count = 1000; // Either "int" or "Integer" OK, depending on need

  public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        synchronized(COUNT_LOCK) {
          count++;
          count--;
          count++;
          count--;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

Another option is to use an `AtomicInteger` which may give better concurrent performance, if that matters:

```
public class ThreadInterference {
  public static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1000);

  public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        count.decrementAndGet();
        count.incrementAndGet();
        count.decrementAndGet();
      }
    }
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

Comment: I really like the suggestion to make the synchronization object `final`, but the rest just repeats earlier answers.

Comment: @user949300, I think it expands on previous answers, but I can understand if you see that differently.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what is happening is this:

`count++` tries to increment an `Integer`, which is immutable.  The compiler must create a new Integer and refer to it as "count".  Synchronization locks on the former count will then behave unexpectly.  Somebody really smart could probably work it out...

Change count to a primitive `int` and synchronize on something else to see what happens.  Or use an AtomicInteger.

Main takeaway is *don't increment Integers!* unless you are sure.

Comment: It still breaks if I change `Integer to int` or change `count++` to `count = count + 1`.

Comment: @FANGYishu You can't synchronize on primitive types so a change to `int` wouldn't even compile. For `count = count + 1`, you're basically doing the same thing as `count++`, so obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: You still have to synchronize on something because ++ is not atomic.  BTW an AtomicInteger would be a good choice too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of synchronizing count,

Try doing increment/decrement method that are themselves synchronized...

```
public static synchronized decrementCount()
{
    count--;
}

public static synchronized incrementCount()
{
    count++;
}
```

And call them instead of directly decrementing/incrementing.

Also, you should use atomic value if you are only doing a counter which prevent thread interference without resorting to synchronization.

Anyway, check this doc which show you how to do a synchronized counter with synchronized methods or atomic values : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this, you are doing it wrong.

```
        public static volatile Integer count = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            synchronized(count) {
                count++;
                count--;
                count++;
                count--;
            }
        }
```

Integer is immuttable. That means, when you are doing `count++`, it created a new `Integer` object, and assigned `count` with that new object. Meanwhile, synchronized part still reference the old object. So there exist a chance when every thread reached synchronized block with different object.
You should use variable that doesn't point to different object when the process happened.